# How to generate 837 DAT file with ICD10 code in Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk, edi, icd

My 'BizTalk' application 'convert' txt file to 'DAT(EDI 837 005010X222A1)' file format.

> 'Now change is Need to generate DAT file with ICD10 code'
>
> Question are
>
> 1. How I generate DAT with like 'HI*ABK'? right now in Combined837Doc.map, 'BK' is hardcoded
> 2. Should I change 'X12_00501_837_P.xsd'?
> 3. How BizTalk decide ABK | ABF | ABN | ABJ HI qualifier based on passed ICD code?

BK ---> Primary Diagnosis code  -->ABK

BF ---> Secondary Diagnosis code -->ABF

BN ---> External Cause of injury -->ABN

BJ ---> Admitting Diagnosis -->ABJ

PR ---> Patient Reason for Visit -->APR

BR ---> Primary Procedure code -->BBR

BQ ---> Secondary Procedure code -->BBQ

Comment: Your "question" has too many questions and on a very specialist subject  and you fail to give much detail. As such you are unlikely to get an answer.  I have worked with BizTalk over 10 years and I don't even know where to start to answer this.   You probably want to split this into three questions and give further details of each of the problem and what you have tried to do to solve it.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - I pretty much agree, but I do think it's helpful to clarify here that there's a part of the question that can be answered in a way that'd be helpful to others - e.g. that BizTalk doesn't handle these codes automatically for you.

Comment: @DanField Thank Dan, I knew that there was some functionality for ICD10 & HIPAA 5010 but have not worked with it.

Comment: So for mapping to the IDC codes I would use the XRef fuctoids in the map. See my blog about it https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/biztalk-pattern-translating-reference-data-in-a-map-using-xref/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BizTalk will not handle this in any sort of automatic way. The 837 XSDs will give you clues about what qualifiers are valid for a particular field, but they do not get set on those fields unless you set them in the map - either in the `Value` property of the destination node or via the output of a link (from a source node or functoid).  You should **not** modify the XSD unless you need to support a non-standard qualifier that you and your trading partner have agreed to use - but you should stick to the standard qualifiers and encourage/require your partners to do so as well to avoid the need of such customization, and if you do make such modifications it should be to a trading partner version of the schema that gets properly mapped to a canonical format that does use the standard codes.

To further clarify, if you need to set the primary diagnosis code to `BK` and set other diagnostic codes to `ABK`, you have to provide that output from the map.  You also have to ensure that you link to the proper `HI` node - only the first `HI` node for the Primary Diagnosis will accept `BK` as the qualifier (per WPC standards); subsequent ones can have `ABK`.  I've written a couple blogs on this topic [here](https://blog.tallan.com/2015/04/30/working-with-hipaa-professional-claim-837p-messages-in-biztalk-part-1/) and [here](https://blog.tallan.com/2015/05/08/working-with-hipaa-professional-claim-837p-messages-in-biztalk-part2/).

What you really need here is to review the WPC specification for the Professional Claim v. 5010 and your trading partner's companion guide for the claim.  These will provide all of this information so you can do your mapping correctly.  You will also very likely need to work with an EDI claims specialist to get this right - HIPAA transactions are particularly challenging, and the claim forms are probably the most complicated of them.